# I'm getting Invalid integer literal c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm trying to enable paging in C# MVC. But I'm getting Invalid Integer literal '62020131100304263882789'. The big long number is actually a unique FaxID number that we created - it's a string. Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal FaxContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(FaxContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetWithRawSql(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return dbSet.SqlQuery(query, parameters).ToList();
    }

    //public IPagedList<T> Search(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filters, string sorting, List<string> includeList, int currentPageNumber, int pageSize)

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(int skip, int take)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(context.Faxes.First().FaxID);

        return query.OrderBy(TEntity => TEntity.).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

        return query.OrderBy(context.Faxes.First().FaxID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing integer value (FaxID) to [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which expects `Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>>` - that's why you see this error.

Use lambda expression to select key from your entity to order results. It should be something like this (assume you have some constraint on TEntity which makes SomeProperty available for you - otherwise ordering does not make sense here):

```
return query.OrderBy(t => t.SomeProperty)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Would you please be so kind to expand what you mean "constraint on TEntity". I'm learning C# MVC and repository pattern. The only properties I see are "Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, and ToString". Thank you.

Comment: @user1828605 I think you have generic repository class. Something like `public class Repository<TEntity>`. Without constraints you have only Object's methods available for variable of type TEntity. If you will put generic parameter constraint to this class (i.e. add `where TEntity: BaseEntity`) then you will have BaseEntity members avaialble

Comment: @user1828605 BTW what field you want to use for sorting in base repository?

Comment: I just edited my question above. You're right, I do have Generic repository. I wanna use the FaxID for the sorting.

Comment: @user1828605 again, what filed you want to use for sorting?

Comment: I got it. Now I know what you mean. Thank you so much for helping me with this one and so quick. You're awesome!!!